# Why am I getting a random negative number on mysql?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I am running the following query, but there is one random result from the TIMESTAMPDIFF function that is returning a negative value, only one:

```
select JOB_ID,FROM_UNIXTIME(TIME_STARTED/1000) as TIME_STARTED,FROM_UNIXTIME(TIME_FINISHED/1000) as TIME_FINISHED,TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,FROM_UNIXTIME(TIME_STARTED/1000, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'),FROM_UNIXTIME(TIME_FINISHED/1000, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')) AS DURATION from JOB;
```

Here's some of the data returned:

```
| job_201306051933_0707 | 2013-06-10 23:16:57 | 2013-06-10 23:17:06 |        9 |
| job_201306051933_0832 | 2013-06-11 10:00:47 | 2013-06-11 10:29:03 |     1696 |
| job_201306051933_0850 | 2013-06-11 12:49:57 | 2013-06-11 13:18:30 |   -41487 |
```

Again, that last one is the only negative value returned and I'm not sure why this is. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using default format for `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to show time_started and time_finished, but to count time difference you convert your timestamps with `'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'` format.

In this format `%h` means hour 01-12 (AM or PM), therefore your time_finished for the last row is taken as '2013-06-11 01:18:30'. It is an earlier timestamp than time_started in the same row so you get a negative result.

You should use `` `%H' `` instead of `'%h'` for hours to get proper value within 00-23 range.
Or use the same default format you use to show timestamps.

Comment: I knew it couldn't be something that hard. Thanks!

Comment: I also found an odd alternative to this:
SELECT * ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,TIME_STARTED,TIME_FINISHED) FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT JOB_ID, FROM_UNIXTIME(TIME_STARTED/1000) AS TIME_STARTED,FROM_UNIXTIME(TIME_FINISHED/1000) AS TIME_FINISHED FROM JOB WHERE USER_SUBMITTED='hddvmktg' ) AS TIMES) AS NEW;